# Removing Divider Line from UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Guys, I know a similar question exists but the thread seems to be inactive, and I really would like this question to be answered. It's been annoying me for a few days now.

**I'm wondering how to remove the divider line between the Master and Detail view in the UISplitViewController.** I know its possible to remove/hide/cover it up because I see some apps in the store without that line.

I have tried setting backgroundColor to clearColour on my views but to no avail. So SO community, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the documented API that allows you to do this. It's mostly playing around with images using an UIImageView to work with that line.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt look a UISplitviewer instead, you can have own views. For example, you can have 2 views in a view controller, where you can apply the design you needed for the views.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't remove the divider between the master and detail view. If you want to hide any one of the view, you can make the view height and width as 0,0 so that the other view will fully occupy the screen

Comment: In this case, how is this sorta view done: http://i.appsafari.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/thingsforipad_480.jpg